# Group my output by years

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I have a DB Projects structure like (ID, projectName, projectDate (MySQL DATE), etc). When I do SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY year(projectDate) DESC
```

Result is:

```
2012 Project 1
2012 Project 2
2011 Project 3
```

I need group projects by year like:

```
2012:
Project 1
Project 2
2011:
Project 3
```

How I can do this without many SQL's queries for any year? I use Smarty for template output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM projects GROUP BY year(projectDate) ORDER BY year(projectDate) DESC
```

ORDER BY alters the order in which items are returned.

GROUP BY will aggregate records by the specified columns which allows you to perform aggregation functions on non-grouped columns (such as SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc).

Comment: Watch out with GROUP BY and ORDER BY in the same query in this case it works.. but this not always give you the results you think http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3924/1 this one is an classic thinking error

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want to do.  You seem to want five rows in your sample output, two containing the "year" values and three containing the "project" values.

These have different numbers and types of columns.

The output from a SQL query consists of a set, where all the rows have the same columns.  Although you could, conceivably, concatenate all the values together into a single column, that is better done in the application.

If you just wanted the project name in this format, you could get it by doing:

```
select ProjectName
from (SELECT ProjectName, year(projectDate) as y, 1 as ordering
      FROM projects 
      union all
      SELECT distinct year(projectDate), year(projectDate), 0
      FROM projects
     ) p
order by y, ordering;
```

Comment: Side note: Watch out with union all on an MySQL server with an large table it could trigger an disk based temporary table what will slow down because disk based IO reads and writes are necessary for the ORDER BY statement.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the best way to do it

```
select 
  year(projectDate) year
 , GROUP_CONCAT(projectName)
from 
 projects
group by 
 year(projectDate) desc
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d11df/3
And explode in php and pass your data to smarty

```
select 
  year(projectDate) year
 , GROUP_CONCAT(projectName SEPARATOR '<br />') as projectName_string
from 
 projects
group by 
 year(projectDate) desc
```

And maybe this will work also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d11df/5